# Как в discord.py сделать настройку языка для каждого сервера дискорд

Tags: база-данных, discord

Я уже давно пытался сделать настройки за счёт БД sqlite3, но ничего не вышло. Можете пожалуйста показать пример кода, для настройки языков для каждого сервера, желательно с sqlite3 или json.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри библиотеку peewee.
Файл models.py описывает базу данных Sqlite3.
В файле utils.py находится функция для добавления и проверки данных о сервере.

файл models.py

```py
from peewee import *


db = SqliteDatabase('data.db')


class DiscordServer(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
        db_table = 'ServerLang'

    id = IntegerField()
    lang = CharField(max_length=20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_tables([DiscordServer])
```

файл utils.py

```py
from models import DiscordServer


def get_server_by_id(user_id):
    try:
        return DiscordServer().get(id=server_id)

    except:
        DiscordServer(
            id=server_id,
            lang='ru'
        ).save()
        return DiscordServer().get(id=server_id)
```